# Disaggregating stock performance and dividend yield

Tags: portfolio-management, dividends, asset-returns

I modeled the performance of several portfolios with adjusted close data and would now like to understand how much of it is driven by changes in stock price and dividend payouts.

I have all the data but am unsure about the right approach.

Does anyone have a pointer where to learn more about doing this?

Any help will be appreciated.